# Navbar - Position element in center and fix navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a navbar and I want to position several elements in three different positions (align left, right and center).

My problem is that the elements in the center, are not centered on the screen, can someone help me solve my problem and understand what my mistake?

Is there also a way to make the navbar fixed, ie when scrolling it never disappears?

Thanks!

**My code [DEMO](https://www.codeply.com/p/OIakCskGtT)**

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn"><img style="width:45px; height:45px" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/2018-social-media-logotypes/1000/2018_social_media_popular_app_logo_reddit-128.png"></a>
          </li>   
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center divBtn">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn"><img style="width:45px; height:45px" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/2018-social-media-logotypes/1000/2018_social_media_popular_app_logo_reddit-128.png"></a>
          </li>   
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
          <li class="nav-item">
             <button>My buttons</button>
              <button>My buttons</button>
          </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
              <button>My buttons</button>
          </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn"><img style="width:45px; height:45px" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/2018-social-media-logotypes/1000/2018_social_media_popular_app_logo_reddit-128.png"></a>
          </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn"> <img style="width:45px; height:45px" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/2018-social-media-logotypes/1000/2018_social_media_popular_app_logo_reddit-128.png">
            </a>
          </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn"><img style="width:45px; height:45px" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/2018-social-media-logotypes/1000/2018_social_media_popular_app_logo_reddit-128.png">
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question, but if I do I think I have the answer, You can do what you write just by giving at the left & right "group" of the navBar a specific margin, **You have to set a div's width first**, in this case each div has a width of 20% (60% tot.), the left div has a margin-right of 20% and then the riht div has a margin-left of 20%, to get everything fully centred you have to set div's text-align to center, **You can run my code just by clicking on run code snippet, below**:

```css
.navBar {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.navBar div {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

.navBar div a  {
    margin: 0 4px;
    padding: 0 4px;;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}



.left {
    margin-right: 20%;
}

.right {
    margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navBar">
        <div class="left">
            <a class="btn" href="#">1</a>
            <a class="btn" href="#">2</a>
            <a class="btn" href="#">3</a>
        </div>

        <div class="center">
            <a href="#" class="btn">4</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn">5</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn">6</a>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <a href="#" class="btn">7</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn">8</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn">9</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To fix the navBar at the top I used "position: fixed" but even "position: sticky" is good.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.topfixed{
    position: sticky !important;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar nabBarContainer topfixed">
        <ul class="nav divBtn">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn"><img style="width:45px; height:45px" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/2018-social-media-logotypes/1000/2018_social_media_popular_app_logo_reddit-128.png"></a>
          </li>   
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center divBtn">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn"><img style="width:45px; height:45px" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/2018-social-media-logotypes/1000/2018_social_media_popular_app_logo_reddit-128.png"></a>
          </li>   
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav justify-content-end divBtn">
          
             <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn"><img style="width:45px; height:45px" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/2018-social-media-logotypes/1000/2018_social_media_popular_app_logo_reddit-128.png">
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div style="height:1000px;"></div>
```

1. To fix van header.. you can add the class below:

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar nabBarContainer topfixed">
```

CSS

```
.topfixed{
        position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Not sure which buttons you want to center.. there 8 buttons.. how do you trying to get them aligned?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, can you post a link / demo?

Comment: You can only position one button in the center, the rest can be on the right and left. This is just a demo

Comment: Please take a look at the snippet

Answer (score 0):

//For fixed navbar:

`position: fixed`;

//For centering an element:

`margin: 0 auto`;

//For placing an element at the right side:

`position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;`

//For placing an element at the left side:

position: absolute;
`left: 0;
top: 0;`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, can you post a link / demo?